# How to increase parallel requests count for razor pages app hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core, web-config, razor-pages

I have a razor pages app hosted in IIS and found out that application can't process more than 6 parallel requests.

**I'm launching multiple parallel ajax requests:**

```
function launchMultipleRequests () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        post('Test'); // just calls $.post({}) inside
}
```

**Razor Page method handling a requests:**

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostTest()
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    return new JsonResult(null);
}
```

What I'm seeing is first 6 requests are starting to work right away but other are queued. After first "batch" is complete, next 6 are being processed and so on.

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Kfw.png)

When I'm running the same code without IIS (IIS express) all requests are processed in parallel and complete in 4 sec.

Comment: Did you face this issue with fiddler or ms Edge? And are you hosting it in client windows OS instead of Server OS?

Comment: @Jokies Ding, I tried this in chrome and new MS edge, result is the same. I've hosted in IIS express (launch from visual studio) and in IIS on Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: IIS shouldn't be limited by 6 requests. What's the status of the hanged requests in IIS worker process monitor?